# If $a \mid 6$ and $b \mid 2$, how to prove $lcm(a,b)$ can't be greater than $6$?

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

In this SE answer about [showing that $\mathbb Z _6 \times \mathbb Z _2 $ doesn't have any element of order $12$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/502476/1021982), we have $(x,y)\in \mathbb Z _6 \times \mathbb Z _2$. It says that $o(x) \mid 6$ and $o(y) \mid 2$. It hence says that $lcm(o(x),o(y))$ is at most  $lcm(2,6) = 6$, which I don't get. Here $o(x)$ denotes the order of $x$.

So far, here is my attempt at finding out why $o(x) \mid 6 \land o(y) \mid 2 \implies lcm(o(x),o(y)) = 6 \text{ at most}$:

I tried to consider the $gcd$ of $o(x)$ and $o(y)$: $(o(x),o(y))$ $$ (o(x),o(y))\mid o(x),o(y) $$ $$ \implies (o(x),o(y)) \mid 6,2 $$ $$\implies 2,6 \mid [o(x),o(y)] $$ the last line being obtained by $(o(x),o(y))[o(x),o(y)] = o(x)o(y)$ where $[o(x),o(y)]$ denotes the $lcm$ of $o(x)$ and $o(y)$.

if anyone could give me a hint at how to do this, I would greatly appreciate.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since $b\mid 2$ and $2\mid 6$, $b\mid 6$. But also $a\mid 6$, so $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)\mid 6\implies \operatorname{lcm}(a,b)\le 6$.

Comment: Hmm, $b$ can only be $1$ or $2$, and $a \in \{1,2,3,6\}$, so even case by case shows your assertion.

Comment: Special case $\,A,B = 6,2\,$ in the linked dupe. $\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $b\mid 2$, then we also have $b\mid 6$. And since $a\mid 6$ and $b\mid 6$, then we immediately have that $6$ is a common multiple of $a$ and $b$. Then it's obvious that $12$ can't be the *least* common multiple.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).